# asp.net mvc how to launch validation of a object before rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, modelstate

I use ASP.NET MVC 2, with Visual Studio 2008 and my view is strongly-typed. The validation using `ValidationAnnotation` works.
What I'm trying to find is how to launch the validation when opening the form. When it opens the model has error, but error doesn't show up. When I press the submit button, the controller validates the model and return to the form.

```
Public Function EditVente(ByVal pNoEnreg As Integer) As ActionResult
            Dim dossierVente As VenteDansMedianePlus = model.Helper.selectDossierVente(pNoEnreg)

        Return View(dossierVente)
    End Function

    Public Function enregistrerVente(ByVal pVente As VenteDansMedianePlus) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            model.Helper.updateDossierVente(pVente)
            Return RedirectToAction("EditVente", "A009P003", New With {Key .pNoEnreg = pVente.noEnreg})
        Else
            Return View("EditVente", pVente)
        End If

    End Function
```

I try to put `ModelState.IsValid` in the `editVente` function, but it doesn't work.

My question is how to launch the model validation before returning the view, so the view has the error message.

Comment: I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347827/validation-messages-are-displayed-when-page-load. That person having my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the TryUpdateModel-method. You can call this method on your controller and pass in your model: (Sorry, I'm a C# developer, hope this is correct)

```
Public Function EditVente(ByVal pNoEnreg As Integer) As ActionResult
     Dim dossierVente As VenteDansMedianePlus = model.Helper.selectDossierVente(pNoEnreg)

     'Update the validation
     TryUpdateModel(dossierVente)

     Return View(dossierVente)
End Function
```

For more information, check this SO post: [When and why do you use TryUpdateModel in asp.net mvc 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268421/when-and-why-do-you-use-tryupdatemodel-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

**Edit**

The TryUpdateModel-method works about the same as the UpdateModel-method, except that UpdateModel throws errors when the validation fails, where TryUpdateModel doesn't.

Comment: Hi, I tried but it give me a error that my object can't be used in tryUpdateModel... But I have to admit that I use updateModel and not tryUpdateModel. I will try it again. If the framework did it easily it should be simple, I'm thinking.

Comment: I will try to call updateModel, but it seems to me that I tried it and it give me a error, I post it tomorrow.

Comment: found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832742/validation-firing-on-page-load. It seems if I can pass a fake parameter it will trigger the model binding mechanism.

Comment: Thanks, tryUpdateModel did work like advertised :). When using updateModel it give this error: "The model of type 'ProportionMediane.VenteDansMedianePlus' could not be updated" I thought updateModel and tryUpdateModel is the same except that tryUpdateModel throws a exception when it fails. Many thanks again first thing I tried this morning and voila it works.

Comment: Good to hear. UpdateModel indeed throws exceptions. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, now I understand, If I wanted to work with updateModel, I should have handle the exception. Thanks again for clearing it up.